# Discontinuation of Alfresco Share?

Tags: alfresco-share

We are using Alfresco (Share/Repository) as a basis for our ECM-Software.

Recently I have found a lot of hints towards the discontinuation of Alfresco Share throughout the web. I have not, however, found solid information like a roadmap or official word from Alfresco.

Has anyone solid information as to if and when Share will finally be discontinued? Has it already been communicated what the intended replacement of share is?

Comment: https://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2018/01/20/4314

Comment: It's only a matter of time when Jeff Potts will see this and maybe add a word or two :)